# How to manage FewArguments Exception?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I have a javascript file which redirect the user to the `Dashboard` controller and invoke the `survey` method like:

```
window.location.href = GlobalVariables.baseUrl + '/dashboard/survey/'+survey_id;
```

the variable `survey_id` is an argument passed in the redirection method. Now suppose that the user just type in the browser the address: `../dashboard/survey` an error will happen eg:

> ArgumentCountError

because the method:

```
public function survey($survey_id)
{
    $this->load->view('products/survey', $survey_id);
}
```

how can I manage this error? Or maybe there is a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this

```
public function survey($survey_id=false)
{
    $this->load->view('products/survey', $survey_id);
}
```